# When is it appropriate to change the accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If I posted a question, and I got an answer that was very good, then I got another answer that is actually more to the point, shorter, easier, and more intuitive. In that case should I change the accepted answer or it would be frowned at ?

In particular I am talking about this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/are-there-any-proofs-the-undecidability-of-the-halting-problem-that-does-not-depe).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My two cents: do whatever you think best.  However, if you find yourself in this situation a lot, you are probably accepting answers too fast.  I usually wait at least a day or two before accepting something, even if I'm pretty sure someone gave me "the" answer right away.

Comment: aaron's answer is perfect.

Comment: Great, just a concern though: how would changing an accepted answer affect the reputation of the user who was accepted first ? will he lose the rep. points he got ?

Comment: Yes. that seems only fair though.